# Unable to call apoc.load.json on Neo4j 3.2.6

Tags: json, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using Neo4j Community Edition 3.2.6 along with apoc-3.2.3.5-all.jar on Mac. When I try to use any query on the browser that contains `call apoc.load.json`, I keep getting `Failed to invoke procedure apoc.load.json: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class apoc.util.JsonUtil`. I can confirm that Neo4j is able to find my jar under plugins directory as `apoc.load.json` is listed when I use `CALL dbms.procedures()`. Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong that I am getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same versions on my Mac, and could not reproduce that error.

If you installed the Neo4j Desktop for OSX, you need to put plugin jar files [in 2 folders](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_download_latest_release):

```
- /Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition\ <version>.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins
- /Users/<user>/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins
```

Comment: I already have them in both places but I realized one was `apoc-3.2.3.5-all.jar` and another one `apoc-3.2.3.5.jar`. I didn't expect them to be different but apparently they are. It is fixed now.